# PHP FPDI - PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

No logro usar la clase Fpdi()... y no entiendo porque no se logra incluir :(

Primero hice un código de ejemplo que funciona perfectamente, este:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
include('/app/resources/fpdf/fpdf.php');
include('/app/resources/fpdi/src/autoload.php');
use \setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;

$filePdf= 'origen.pdf';
$guiaPdf= 'guia.pdf';
$filePdfOut= 'salida.pdf';
$pdfArr= array($filePdf, $guiaPdf); // los PDF's

$pdf= new Fpdi();

foreach( $pdfArr as $f ) {
    $pageCount= $pdf->setSourceFile($f);
    for( $pN=1; $pN<=$pageCount; $pN++ ) {
        $template= $pdf->importPage($pN);
        $size= $pdf->getTemplateSize($template);
        $pdf->AddPage($size["orientation"], $size);
        $pdf->useTemplate($template);
    }
}

$pdf->Output("F", $filePdfOut);
?>
```

Como el código de ejemplo que hice **funciona**, entonces al momento de incorporarlo a mi aplicación, dentro de un PHP llamado **modulos.php** agregue la llamada así:

```
# cat /app/modulos/modulos.php

<?php
... otros includes...
...

use \setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;
include('/app/resources/fpdf/fpdf.php');
include('/app/resources/fpdi/src/autoload.php');
?>
```

Y en el pedazo de código donde uso la llamada a la clase **Fpdi()** me sale este error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Fpdi' not found in
> /var/www/html/api/payload/04-doctosUps.php:18

Así que, copie y pegue los includes con el *use* y me cambia el error por este otro:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in
> /var/www/html/api/payload/04-doctosUps.php on line 19

Por donde podría empezar a indagar para resolver el problema?

**-- UPDATE 03/14/2024, 08:09**

He cambiado el archivo de **modulos.php** dejándolo así:

```
# cat /app/modulos/modulos.php

<?php
... otros includes...
...

// use \setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;
include('/app/resources/fpdf/fpdf.php');
include('/app/resources/fpdi/src/autoload.php');
?>
```

He omitido también la llamada de *use \setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;*, pero aun así, salta el sig. error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Fpdi' not found in
> /var/www/html/api/payload/04-doctosUps.php:20

Despues de ver este error, agrego la llamad a "use" justo encima de la llamada a la clase new Fpdi();, y el error cambia por este otro:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in
> /var/www/html/api/payload/04-doctosUps.php on line 20

**-- UPDATE 03/14/2024, 08:44**

He optado por llamar a la clase Fpdi(); justo despues de incluir el auto load y usar dicha variable en la parte del codigo donde lo necesito invocar y me da este nuevo error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
> setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\CrossReference\CrossReferenceException:
> The xref position points to an incorrect object type. in
> /var/www/html/resources/fpdi/src/PdfParser/CrossReference/CrossReference.php:264\nStack
> trace:\n#0
> /var/www/html/resources/fpdi/src/PdfParser/CrossReference/CrossReference.php(209):
> setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\CrossReference\CrossReference->initReaderInstance()\n#1
> /var/www/html/resources/fpdi/src/PdfParser/CrossReference/CrossReference.php(67):
> setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\CrossReference\CrossReference->readXref()\n#2
> /var/www/html/resources/fpdi/src/PdfParser/PdfParser.php(158):
> setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\CrossReference\CrossReference->__construct()\n#3
> /var/www/html/resources/fpdi/src/PdfParser/PdfParser.php(206):
> setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\PdfParser->getCrossReference()\n#4
> /var/www/html/resources/fpdi/src/PdfParser/PdfParser.php(182):
> setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\PdfParser->getCatalog()\n#5
> /var/www/html/resources/fpdi/src/PdfReader/PdfReader.php(84):
> setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\PdfParser->getPdfVersion()\n# in
> /var/www/html/resources/fpdi/src/PdfParser/CrossReference/CrossReference.php
> on line 264

El cambio que hice en **modulos.php** fue:

```
<?php
include('/app/resources/fpdf/fpdf.php');
include('/app/resources/fpdi/src/autoload.php');
use \setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;
$fpdiService= new Fpdi();
?>
```

Comment: Si usas [autoload](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.autoload.php), no tienes que requerir los demás archivos de las clases, precisamente esa es una de las características de autoload, evitar tener que ir poniendo `require` o `include` por todas partes. Simplemente, haz el `include('/app/resources/fpdi/src/autoload.php');` al principio de tu archivo, y luego pon los `use` de todas las clases que quieras importar. Podrías considerar también usar espacios de nombre.

Comment: @A.Cedano he quitado la llamada de use, modificado "modulos.php", pero aun persiste el error... verifica la parte de **-- UPDATE 03/14/2024, 08:09** en delante

Comment: A ver, creo que no me he explicado bien. ¿Qué significa ese `... otros includes...`? Como ya dije, si usas *autoload* no tienes que poner include de nada, sino simplemente poner los `use` de las clases que quieres usar en ese contexto y punto. Y los `use` deben ir al principio del archivo. Si no funciona, puede que tu autoload esté mal escrito o que no hayas respetado una convención al nombrar los archivos de tus clases. Creo que estás confundiendo las cosas, pues intentas usar *autoload* y también `include`. *autoload* es una alternativa superior a `include`, no es para usar una y otra.

Comment: @A.Cedano el termino de "... otros includes.." me refiero a que llamo otras clases que uso para otros temas/cosas, osea, nada asociado con FPDI, pero estoy omitiendo mencionar dichas llamadas ya que no sirven para el presente post, vaya, POR EJEMPLO tengo el include() de la clase "sendinblue", tengo el include de la llamada a "phpexcel" y asi...

Comment: Pero es que si usas autoload no tienes que hacer include de esas clases, sino importarlas con `use \EspacioDeNombre\LaClase`